# Why does the .Find function appear to not work properly in this code?

Tags: vba, replace, directory, ms-word, find

The program is supposed to loop through a directory to find every occurrence of a word from a list that is in another word document and expand selection to the whole question. This program is supposed to allow you to compile a list of test questions from a test bank based on a list of highly relevant key terms. Eventually, once all the relevant questions are selected They would be copied to a new document.

```
Sub CompareWordList()
'program to loop through Directory to find every occurrence of a word from a list and expand selection to
'the whole question. This program is supposed to allow you to compile a list of test questions from a
'test bank based on a list of highly relevent key terms. Eventually, once all the relevent questions are selected
'They would be copied to a new document
'variables for directory looping
Dim vDirectory As String
Dim oDoc As Document

'generates file path
vDirectory = "D:\school\documents\MGT450\Test_Bank\TB - test\" 'set directory to loop through

vFile = Dir(vDirectory & "*.*") 'file name

'variables for selection
Dim sCheckDoc As String
Dim docRef As Document
'Dim docCurrent As Document
Dim wrdRef As Object

 'list of words to look for
sCheckDoc = "D:\testlist.docx"
Set docRef = Documents.Open(sCheckDoc)
'docCurrent.Activate
docRef.Activate
'Directory Loop
Do While vFile <> ""
    Set oDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=vDirectory & vFile)
'document activation
oDoc.Activate
SendDocToArray_FindWords (sCheckDoc)





'Havent really worked on this area yet, as been focused on find issue
docRef.Close
'close document modification

    oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    vFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
'After every instance of a particular phrase is selected, select question 
around said phrase
Function SelectQuestion(Index As Long)
'iniitial declaration
Dim linecount As Integer
Set mydoc = ActiveDocument
Dim oPara As word.Paragraph
'Dim oPara As selection
Dim ListLevelNumber As Integer
Dim holder As Long

    'if list type is simple numbering
    If selection.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering Or 
 wdListBullet Or wdListMixedNumbering Then
        'Select Whole Question containing word
        With selection
         .StartIsActive = False
         .Extend Character:=";"
         .EndKey
         .StartOf (wdLine)
        End With
       a = selection.MoveUntil(";", wdBackward)
       b = selection.MoveDown(wdLine, 2, wdMove)

    selection.StartOf (wdLine)
    selection.Find.Execute "*^13^13", , , True

    'some correction of range- remove last paragraph from selection
    ActiveDocument.Range(selection.Start, selection.End - 1).Select
    End If




End Function

Function GetParNum(r As Range) As Integer
'determines paragraph number
GetParNum = selection.Range.ListFormat.ListValue
End Function
Sub Test() 'testing function
CountWords

End Sub

Function SendDocToArray_FindWords(name As String) As Variant
'sends a document to an array split by newline
'the document that is send to the array is composed of the words that are
'being searched for.
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = Documents.Open(name)
Dim arr() As String
arr() = Split(doc.Content.Text, Chr(13))
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim targetRng As Range


For Each i In arr()

Dim r As Range
Dim j As Long
Set r = ActiveDocument.Content


With r.Find

'If I pass a variable to FindText it only finds the first instance of the word then
'prematurely exits loop or becomes an infinite loop
'strangely the function is only working when I hardcode the word such as
'FindText:= "International Business"
Do While .Execute(FindText:=i, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue) = True
    If r.Find.Found = True Then
    j = j + 1

    End If

Loop
End With
MsgBox "The Word" & i & " was found " & j & " times."



Next i
MsgBox ("Finished Selecting")
End Function

'testing count words function
Function CountWords(c As String)  'ByRef word As Variant
'counts number of occurences of words in document
Dim r As Range
Dim j As Long
Set r = ActiveDocument.Content

'ResetFRParameters r
With r.Find

'.Wrap = wdFindContinue
Do While .Execute(FindText:=i, Forward:=True) = True
If r.Find.Found = True Then
j = j + 1

End If

Loop
End With
MsgBox "Given word(s) was found " & j & " times."

End Function
'testing count words function
Sub FindText()
Dim MyAR() As String
Dim i As Long

i = 0

selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
selection.Find.Text = "International Business"
' selection.Range.Text
Do While selection.Find.Execute = True
    ReDim Preserve MyAR(i)
    MyAR(i) = selection
    i = i + 1
Loop

If i = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Matches Found"
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = LBound(MyAR) To UBound(MyAR)
    MsgBox ("# of International Business occurrences " & i)
Next i
End Sub
```

I used three finds that I was trying to get to work correctly but they do not appear to search the whole document regardless how I use them. I have started wondering if the formatting of my document is to blame. I have attached both an image of the list of terms as well as document to search through.
[This is the list of terms to search through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqnG5.png)
[This is the document to search through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPZM9.png)

My ultimate question is how do I get around this problem and find all instances of the given search term in the document? As of now it either finds the first instance and breaks or becomes an infinite loop.

This is the final that works, although not he prettiest, for others who may be looking for similar code: (pasting it here as messed up the format a bit so youll need to fix those if you use it)

```
 Sub TraversePath()
 Dim fso As Object 'FileSystemObject
 Dim fldStart As Object 'Folder
 Dim fld As Object 'Folder
 Dim fl As Object 'File
 Dim Mask As String '.doc,.docx,.xlsx, etc

 Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject") ' late binding
 'Set fso = New FileSystemObject 'or use early binding (also replace Object 
 types)

Set fldStart = fso.GetFolder("D:\school\documents\MGT450\Test_Bank\TB - 
test\") ' Base Directory

Mask = "*.doc"

ListFiles fldStart, Mask
'for each file in folder
'For Each fl In fldStart
'    ListFiles fld, Mask
MsgBox ("Fin.")
'Next
End Sub


Sub ListFiles(fld As Object, Mask As String)
Dim runTracker As Integer
runTracker = 0
Dim fl As Object 'File
x = NewDoc 'generate new processed study guide
Dim sCheckDoc As String
Dim docRef As Document
Dim vFile As String
Dim arr() As String
'list of words to look for
sCheckDoc = "D:\testlist.docx"
Set docRef = Documents.Open(sCheckDoc)

docRef.Activate
'send docref to array split by newline
arr() = Split(docRef.Content.Text, Chr(13))
'begin word array loop?
For Each fl In fld.Files
    runTracker = runTracker + 1
    If fl.name Like Mask Then
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------run 
 program code

        vFile = fl.name 'set vFile = current file name
        a = Documents.Open(fld.path & "\" & fl.name) 'open current search 
file
        Documents(vFile).Activate 'activate current search file

        For a = 0 To UBound(arr)

             'reset selection
             selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
             'Inform progress
             StatusBar = "Running Find..."

             Dim docB As String
                 docB = Documents("Processed_StudyGuide.docx")
             Dim docA As String
                 docA = Documents(vFile)
                 Documents(docA).Activate

             b = DoFindReplace_Bkmk(arr(a))
             'print bookmarked values to new document
             StatusBar = "Printing targeted paragraphs..."
             PrintBookmarks (bookmarkName)
             If b <> 0 Then
                    'notify how many were inserted
                    MsgBox ("Complete, inserted: " & b & " bookmarks of " & 
arr(a))

             End If

        Next a

        MsgBox ("finished find in: " & vFile)
        Documents(vFile).Close (wdDoNotSaveChanges)
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------end 
code
    End If
Next
MsgBox ("Finished all documents")
End Sub

 Function SelectQuestion(Index As Long)
 'iniitial declaration
 Dim linecount As Integer
 Dim oPara As word.Paragraph
 'Dim oPara As selection
 Dim ListLevelNumber As Integer
 Dim holder As Long

'if list type is simple numbering
If selection.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering Or 
wdListBullet Or wdListMixedNumbering Then
    'Select Whole Question containing word
    With selection
     .StartIsActive = False
     .Extend Character:=";"
     .EndKey
     .StartOf (wdLine)
    End With
a = selection.MoveUntil(";", wdBackward)
b = selection.MoveDown(wdLine, 2, wdMove)

selection.StartOf (wdLine)
selection.Find.Execute "*^13^13", , , True

'some correction of range- remove last paragraph from selection
'ActiveDocument.Range(selection.start, selection.End - 1).Select
End If
End Function
Function GetParNum(r As Range) As Integer
'determines paragraph number
GetParNum = selection.Range.ListFormat.ListValue
End Function
Function NewDoc() As String
'Generate new document and save
a = Documents.Add(, , , True)
ActiveDocument.Content.Delete
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 ("D:\Processed_StudyGuide")
End Function
Public Function GetName(num As Integer) As String
'names each bookmark
Dim t As String
Dim nameArr() As Variant
nameArr = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", 
"m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "aa", 
"bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg", "hh", "ii", "jj", "kk", "ll", "mm", 
"nn", "oo", "pp", "qq", "rr", "ss", "tt", "uu", "vv", "ww", "xx", "yy", 
"zz", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", 
"kkk", "lll", "mmm", "nnn", "ooo", "ppp", "qqq", "rrr", "sss", "ttt", "uuu", 
"vvv", "www", "xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd", "eeee", 
"ffff", "gggg", "hhhh", "iiii", "jjjj", "kkkk", "llll", "mmmm", "nnnn", 
"oooo", "pppp", "qqqq", "rrrr", "ssss", "tttt", "uuuu", "vvvv", "wwww", 
"xxxx", "yyyy", "zzzz", "aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd")

t = nameArr(num)
GetName = t
End Function

Function PrintBookmarks(name As String) 'Add each selection to collection
'Declarations
selection.Collapse
Dim n As Integer
Dim docB As String
docB = Documents("Processed_StudyGuide.docx")
Dim docA As String
docA = ActiveDocument.name
Dim x As Integer
x = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count
Dim a As String


For Each bkmark In Documents(docA).Bookmarks
'If # of bookmarks is greater than 0 select the one at x
If x > 0 Then
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(x)
        BkMkName = .name
        .Select
    End With
End If
'selection.Bookmarks(a).Select
SelectQuestion (GetParNum(selection.Range))
selection.Copy
selection.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
Documents("Processed_StudyGuide.docx").Activate
selection.MoveEnd
selection.Paste

'reactivate last document
Documents(docA).Activate
x = x - 1
Next

'runs bookmark removal
removebookmarks (docA)
Documents(docB).Activate 'activate processed study guide
'    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Count > 0 Then
'    FixRepeatedQuestions
'    End If
removebookmarks (docB)
ActiveDocument.Save
Documents(docA).Activate
End Function

Sub removebookmarks(name As String)
'removes bookmarks from documents
Dim bkm As Bookmark
For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
bkm.Delete
Next bkm
End Sub
Function DoFindReplace_Bkmk(ByRef FindText As Variant, Optional ReplaceText 
As String) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Dim bkmark As String


With selection.Find
'set Find Parameters
.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Text = FindText
'If replacement text is not supplied replace with targetword to find
If ReplaceText = "" Then
.Replacement.Text = FindText
Else
.Replacement.Text = ReplaceText
End If
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
Do While .Execute
    'Keep going until nothing found
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    'keep track of how many are replaced

    'get bookmark name and add bookmark at location
    bookmarkName = GetName(i)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add name:=bookmarkName, Range:=selection.Range
    i = i + 1 'below because array starts at 0
Loop
'Free up some memory
ActiveDocument.UndoClear
End With
'return # of find/replacements
DoFindReplace_Bkmk = i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`For Each i In arr()` can't work.

Your Arr() is a string and the Each enumeration only works for objects. You would have to use

```
For i = 0 to Ubound(Arr)
Next i
```

Here is the complete code for repetitive searching. Note that the `TestCount` function prints its output to VBE's Immediate window. If you don't see it, press Ctl+G or select it from the View menu, or change the output to a MsgBox.

```
Sub TestCount()
    ' testing procedure

    Dim MyPhrase As String

    MyPhrase = "International business"
    Debug.Print "My phrase was found " & CountWords(MyPhrase) & " times."
End Sub

Function CountWords(Phrase As String) As Integer
    ' 12 Apr 2017
    ' return the number of occurences of words in document

    Dim Fun As Integer                      ' Function return value
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    Do
        With Rng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchCase = False
            .Text = Phrase
            .Execute
            If Not .Found Then Exit Do

            Fun = Fun + 1
        End With
    Loop
    CountWords = Fun
End Function
```

For your understanding:-

1. `Find` always starts the search at the beginning of the range you set. At the start of the procedure the range is defined as `ActiveDocument.Content`.
2. When a match is found, the range is reset to hold only the found phrase, meaning `Rng` isn't the same as it was before.
3. The loop now repeats the search with the changed `Rng` object, again starting at the beginning of that range to the end of the document.
4. When no more match is found the loop is exited. It's important, not to Wrap because that property instructs `Find` to continue looking for matches at the beginning of the document when no match is found before its end.

In between, in the place where you now see `Fun = Fun + 1`, you could execute any code you like - perhaps call a sub there which makes major changes or even copies parts of the document to another document. The important thing is that, after you come back from all that work, the `Rng` pointer still holds that part of the document from where you want to continue your search.

O hope this will speed you on your way.

Comment: Made changes you indicated. Still only finds first instance then breaks loop in FindText() prematurely.  @Variatus

Comment: Thank you that has helped a lot @Variatus